# seekingalpha.com earnings transcripts scraper

Tags: python, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook, web-crawler

do you have any idea how to get this genius code for scraping earnings transcripts from seekingalpha.com running again?

Script can be found here: https://github.com/RCJansonVTFL/SeekingAlphaWebScrape/blob/main/MGMT%20Final%20w%20Entities_Compiled_Final.ipynb

I have tried a lot because it seems that seekingalpha implemented some countermeasures against scraping. I have modified my chromedrivers and also my selenium setting to avoid being detected from the website but it didn't work. I have also signed up for a premium account to avoid captcha and to have unlimited access but this also didn't work out. Any idea what to do?

Comment: Hallo and welcome to SO! Please provide the code you tried and point to the lines that give the error.

Comment: Hi @CatalinaChircu, thanks for your reply. Actually, I have tried a lot but I am not sure how to handle or lets say avoid the captchas. I tried to use a login with premium account but also some other hints such as randomuseragents, removing cdc from chromedriver, undetected_chromedriver.v2,...

`driver.find_element_by_id("sign-in").click()`

`NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-515cc9131c2d> in <module>
     25 
     26 
---> 27 driver.find_element_by_id("sign-in").click()
     28 # box = 'alphabox-modal-window'
     29 `